# How can I play a sound in onclick event in PhoneGap/Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, audio

I've been searching for hours but really I don't find answer, and many of the answers that I find, don't work for me.

I'm working on an entertainment application where there are several buttons and pressing each one, generates a different sound. The problem is that I can't get play the sound. I tried the plugin half, and another things, and I really think I'm too lost haha, I hope you can help me. I am a beginner at this, so any comments / suggestions / help is more than welcome, really.

This is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.carlosmdnv.appname" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>App Title</name>
    <description>
        Description here.
    </description>
    <author email="contacto@carlosmdnv.com" href="http://www.carlosmdnv.com">
        Carlos Medina
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />

    <icon src="www/img/icon.png"/>

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.core.Device"/>

   <feature name="Media">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler" />
   </feature>
</widget>
```

My index.js:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    function playAudio(id) {
    var audioElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var url = audioElement.getAttribute('src');
    var my_media = new Media('/android_asset/www/' + url,
            // success callback
             function () { console.log("playAudio():Audio Success"); },
            // error callback
             function (err) { console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err); }
    );
           // Play audio
    my_media.play();
});
```

And my index.html elements:

```
<div onclick="playAudio('successSound')"></div>
<audio id="successSound" src="mp3/sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: there is missing }. Add it before my_media.play();